# How Long is Australia visa valid for?

Tags: visas, australia, nigerian-citizens

How long is Australia tourist visa valid for? Especially for Nigerian Citizens?

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer**: If granted, an Australian visa for tourism may have a three-month, six-month, or twelve-month validity.

**Long Answer**: [This Australia government page](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder) is a visa wizard. Entering your travel purpose as "Visit and Tourism" then "Holiday," and your Nigerian citizenship, the wizard displays the result [on this page](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder/visit) as follows:

> What's the main purpose of your visit? **a holiday**
> What's your country of passport? **Nigeria**
>
> Here are 2 visas that match your criteria
>
> **Tourist Stream (apply outside Australia)**
> This visa stream lets you visit Australia as a tourist, to go on a cruise or to see family and friends.
> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​We might grant you a stay of 3, 6 or 12 months
> Visit friends and family, cruise or have a holiday
> You must be outside Australia when you apply and when we decide your visa.
>
> **Stay**
> Up to 12 months
>
> **Cost**
> From AUD150
>
> **Processing Time**
>
> - 25% of applications: Less than 1 Day
> - 50% of applications: 6 Days
> - 75% of applications: 26 Days
> - 90% of applications: 37 Days
>
> Due to COVID-19, some visa processing times have been affected and applications may take longer to finalise.
>
> *(Other notes omitted)*
>
> **Tourist stream (apply in Australia)**
> This visa stream lets you visit Australia as a tourist, to see family and friends or for purposes other than business or medical treatment.
> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​We might grant you a stay of up to 12 months
> Visit friends and family, cruise or have a holiday
> If you hold another visa that is expiring and want to stay longer, this visa might suit you
> You must be in Australia when you apply and when we decide your application.
>
> **Stay** Up to 12 months
>
> **Cost** From AUD380
>
> **Processing Time**
>
> - 25% of applications: Less than 1 Day
> - 50% of applications: 6 Days
> - 75% of applications: 26 Days
> - 90% of applications: 37 Days
>
> Due to COVID-19, some visa processing times have been affected and applications may take longer to finalise.
>
> *(Other notes omitted)*

Answer (score 4):

The [subclass 600 Tourist Stream page](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600/tourist-stream-overseas#About) says

> Generally, we grant a stay period of 3 months. We might grant a stay of up to 12 months in certain circumstances.

I couldn't find a source stating official policy for 'arrive by' dates but for reference my family were granted visas with 'arrive by' dates one year from the visa grant date.

e.g. if the grant date is 26 August 2022 and the 'arrive by' date is 26 August 2023 and the stay period is three months, you can arrive on or before 26 August 2023 and stay for up to three months.